# If I have an angle theta, what does sin theta and cos theta returns?

Tags: trigonometry

does sin theta returns y? also, does cos theta returns x?

I am confused because in my program sin theta returns dy and cos theta returns dx.  dx and dy are very less than x and y.

Comment: can you give us an example please?

Comment: The angle $\theta$ alone doesn't determine a point, it determines a ray from the origin. This ray meets the unit circle in a unique point; the x-coordinate of this point is indeed $\cos \theta$, and the y-coordinate of this point is $\sin\theta$. Of course, the readers here have no idea what program you mention, or what you mean by $dx$ and $dy$ without more information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a right triangle with hypotenuse of length $1$ and angle $\theta$ which has legs parallel to the axis and one vertex in the origin. Then the legs measure $\cos(\theta)$ and $\sin(\theta)$, so the point that is touching the circle in the image has coordinates $(\cos\theta,\sin\theta)$

[image]

Comment: So before measuring an angle, I have to translate the line to the origin, right?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean.

Comment: I am asking - is angle always measured from the origin ?

Comment: If you have to measure an angle that is not at the origin you can pretend it is and then add the coordinates of the original point (which is not the origin).